# flask-admin: Render inline_models as list view?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a `Motion` model which has many `Votes`. I display the votes as an `inline_model` in `flask-admin`. Is it possible to render the votes as a table like in the `list_view` template? Instead of like this:

[image: inline_models list]

Answer (score 0):

Using using rules from flask-admin you can change the way either the create form or the edit form looks.

```
class View(sqla.ModelView):
    form_create_rules = {
        #for instance
        attribute1,
        rules.Header('A header'),
        attribute2
    }
```

If you want more customization you can also use formatters

```
class View(sqla.ModelView):
    form_create_rules = {
        #for instance
        attribute1,
        rules.Header('A header'),
        attribute2
    }

def _a_column_formatter(view, context, model, name):
    #returns the content of a row in h3 html tags
    return Markup('<h3>{}</h3>'.format(model.attribute))

column_formatters = {
    'ticket_name': _a_column_formatter
}
```

Have a look at http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters