# Flask admin show inline_models as list

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I try to create a Flask-Admin view with inline_models.

This works, but it renders the inline item by item.

```
class MyViewFeatureEngineering(sqla.ModelView):
    inline_models = ((Feature_columns),)
```

But I would like to show it as a list.

It can be either editable, or read-only with column_editable_list set for a few columns.

Is this possible with Flask-Admin, or is this the moment to switch to fully customized templates? So far it seemed that almost everything could be overwritten to ones needs.

Thanks

Comment: I assume something similar to a Django admin TabularInline?

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731991/flask-admin-render-inline-models-as-list-view